# removing all the string content before a certain string in an NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, substring

I am trying to see if there is a short way of doing the following:

let s say I have the following NSString: 
`@"123456 copy cat";`

I need to remove everything before "copy" and the length of the text before it is variable (depends on the user input)

I know that I can probably do an endless for loop to check the substring but I hope that there is a faster way

Comment: You can't remove anything from an NSString.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"123456 copy cat";
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"copy"];
NSString *newString = [string substringFromIndex:range.location];
```

That's the simple answer. The problem is that your user may enter the word 'copy', and then what? Even if you get the range this way:

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"copy cat"];
```

there's still a chance your user may enter that phrase as well. By the time you put in additional checks, it's no longer a "short way."

**EDIT**

Don't overlook Chuck's excellent observation in the comments for using:

`-[NSString rangeOfString:options:]`

Comment: this is correct, but this will only work with the first instance "copy" to make it greedy you would have to do it in a loop and see if it keeps getting shorter.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: To use the last occurrence of "copy" instead of the first, just use `[string rangeOfString:@"copy" options:NSBackwardsSearch]`. No need for a loop.

Answer (score 2):

To remove part of a string you will either have to create a new string containing the part that you want to keep, or create a mutable copy of your string and modify that.

To create a new string containing the part starting with "copy":

```
NSString *input;
NSString *output;
NSRange copyRange;

input = @"123456 copy cat";
copyRange = [input rangeOfString:@"copy"];
output = [input substringFromIndex:copyRange.location];
```

To create a mutable string and remove the part up to "copy":

```
NSString *input;
NSMutableString *output;
NSRange copyRange;

input = @"123456 copy cat";
output = [input mutableCopy];
copyRange = [output rangeOfString:@"copy"];
[output replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, copyRange.location) withString:@""];
[output autorelease]; // depending on what you want to do
```

Please also see the comments in the other answer about using rangeOfString:withOptions: with NSBackwardsSearch in case the user input also contains the word "input".